# openSUSE frozen on login screen, refuses to return to GUI

Tags: linux, bash, kde, opensuse, startx

I just came back to my recently installed (overnight last night, just started using it today) openSUSE installation to find it frozen on the lock screen. After various attempts to get it to unfreeze I pressed `ctrl + alt + f1`, booted into bash and ran `startx`, only to find the following error message:

[image: Picture of error message]

To make matters worse, after running the `startx` command for the second time, the system won't even return to the Linux prompt. Anyone got any idea what's going on and how to fix it?

Update: managed to get back to Linux prompt with `Ctrl + Alt + F3`...

Update: trying to run `Xorg` separately and attempting to check the Xorg logs doesn't help either:

[image: Attempting to check Xorg]

Update: after running `rcxdm stop` command to restart the KDE and xserver instances, the machine shows the following error:

[Additional error screen](http://Jetez%20un%20coup%20d'%C5%93il%20au%20Tweet%20de%20@theflatworm%20:%20https://twitter.com/theflatworm/status/720622383674081280?s=09)

And will not accept any command-line input at all.

Comment: The issue did not go away on its own. It is reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the system working again by pressing `Ctrl + Alt + F3` one more time, which got me back to the root terminal. From there I ran `startx` again; this time KDE started and I'm now back into my system (minus all cached information, everything I was working on, and for some odd reason the sound drivers...).

Comment: Looks like you were running `startx` as root. So no wonder your session information got "lost", if your previous sessions were started as a different user.

Comment: Why would running as root cause my information to get lost?

Comment: Since the desktop session is store in the home folder of the logged in user. So when you log in with root and start an X session it will use the root home folder and not your normal user. The information is still in you normal users home folder.